# Using PowerShell created self signed certs

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am trying to create a new self signed cert and then use it to sign an EXE, to address the fact that idiot Autodesk is using an installer that ignores the time stamp and refuses to install something with an expired cert, even their own installer. It's a bug, they know it, and they fixed their installer. But addressing that when you have 30+ deployments that use the old buggy one is a PITA. Anyway...

I expected this would produce a certificate that I would find in the Personal tab.

```
$certParameters = @{
    'DnsName'           = 'PxTools'
    'Type'              = 'CodeSigningCert'
    'CertStoreLocation' = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
    'NotAfter'          = (Get-Date).AddMonths(12)
    'KeyAlgorithm'      = 'RSA'
    'KeyLength'         = '4096'
}
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @certParameters
```

and that I would then be able to use it for signing. But it doesn't populate the `$cert` variable as expected, and it puts the cert in `Intermediate Certification Authorities`, and I have yet to figure out how to use

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\?? -codesign
```

To get certs in that location. I have used ??=My to get a cert in Personal, but not sure
A: Why the cert isn't created in Personal as expected
B: How to get the cert from where it IS created

Comment: @olaf Good point, and I tried both. Should have mentioned that. I was cutting and pasting from the ISE with my last attempt. Grasping at straws really.

Comment: At least I can see the cert I just created with your snippet for testing without issues.

Comment: You could try t osearch for `Get-ChildItem cert:\* -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Subject -match 'PxTools'}`

Comment: Hmm, that is getting me there. But my VM now has multiple certs, and using `[0]` to just get the first one isn't working. I may need to roll back the VM and try again with a single cert.

Comment: Actually, `[0]` is working, but when I try to sign with `SignTool` it fails. I am only using tat because I still haven't figured out why `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` no longer works for me. Sigh.

Comment: Wat error do you get with `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` ?

Comment: UnknownError. Happens with a real cert too, both file based and from the cert store. Been driving me nuts for weeks now.